# Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer extension

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, solution-explorer

I need a little VS 2012 solution explorer extension and need your help.
I already made a extension for VS, but never for the solution explorer.

What I need is simply, I think...

I have a class called "test.cs" in folder "a" and now I add a file "test.abc" to folder "a" and what I want is to place the ".abc" file "hidden under" the ".cs" file and place a plus button beside the class file which I can click and than its collapsed and I see the ".abc" file.

VS 2012 do the exact same for example for the global.asax or web.config files.

Can someone help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nested project file by defining a VS Project Item Template with an accompanying assembly that implements `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard`. In your assembly you would create any additional file to be nested within the templated file.

Here's a good tutorial on how to put it all together:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23182/Create-Item-Templates-Which-Have-Nested-Items